# Add marks at specified times on a Munin graph

Tags: monitoring, munin

I want to mark some events on my Munin graphs to see how the graphs change at these points. It seems that in RRD terms they can be created by `VRULE` command, but I can't find a way to use it with Munin. Essentially I want to pass a list of `time:caption` or at least just `time` values and ideally see the corresponding lines on all graphs.

if this is not possible with Munin, is there a similar monitoring system (with custom plugin support) that allows it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Munin (and many of the other Linux based monitoring products) use `rrdtool` in the background as you've seen.  The benefit of that is you can build your own graphs really easily outside of the tool.  I suggest you just write a shell script which creates a couple of graphs you need with the relevant `VRULE` entries.  The advantage is you'll be able to combine any data you want over any time period (assuming it's still present).  You could either just output images into a directory and browse to them or you could wrap some html / php around them.

I view Munin (and similar products, although I prefer Munin) as primarily a set of data collection scripts, with a default front end.  Munin can do some customisation and consolidation but since it's collected the data, and since the interface to rrdtool is pretty simple, I prefer just to create as many custom graphs as I want on an adhoc basis.