# How to mark every deploy in munin?

Tags: monitoring, deployment, munin

Anyone knows if it's possible to mark every deploy with a red vertical line in munin graphs? It will be great to debug possible performance holes in the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Interesting question which I'm very curious about finding a solution. I think it's possible to do this with a hack. Create a simple plugin that returns e.g. "100" on a deploy, and "0" all other time. Configure this plugin to use `--upper-limit 100`. I'm not sure how this would work when data gets truncated and you're viewing this on a year-visualization and this is definitely not tested.

Comment: thanks for your comment pkhamre. for what I understand, you are saying that one option could be create a plugin that generates a new graph with the vertical line marking the deploy, am I right? 

I'm thinking more in drawing that line on every other munin graph simultaneously, so it's directly visible directly in any graph.

Comment: Yeah, that was my initial thought. I think you might want to look at Graphite instead. This is very esy to do with it.

Comment: ok, thanks a lot pkharme, I will take a look to it ;)

Comment: Check out these https://blog.mozilla.org/webdev/2012/04/05/tracking-deployments-in-graphite/ and http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2010/12/08/track-every-release/

Comment: This [has been asked before](http://serverfault.com/questions/290033/add-marks-at-specified-times-on-a-munin-graph) and the only answer given at the time was "write your own script to do it".

Comment: This answer is mostly off topic, but all your current and future problems (and most needs) with munin will be solved by switching to graphite. There you can combine multiple graphs on the fly. So you can have one datastore that holds the deployments or other events and then project that on top of every other graph. Plus all the goodies that the on-the-fly post-processing ability of graphite offers.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in munin today.

I've added a [ticket](https://github.com/munin-monitoring/munin/issues/563) for it in the munin issue tracker, since it's something I'd like to add to munin.

Answer (score -1):

In Zabbix, I check the md5sum of every script and notify the changes to sysadmin team.

Thinking that way, if you select some key points of your application, you'll able to get the deploys.

Also, you should give Graphite a chance or write your own munin plugin.

http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/HowToWritePlugins

Comment: The question was not about detecting deploys, but about marking them on one or all graphs